# ios NSUinteger to type 'id'

Tags: ios

My brain is failing me today. I know this has got to be a simple one, but I just don't see it.

```
CGFloat *minutes = [self.displayData objectForKey:index];
```

*Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int') to parameter of type 'id'*

`index` is a `NSUInteger` in a loop, (0 1 2 3 etc)

How do I get past this one? Thanks.

Comment: `objectForKey:` != `objectAtIndex:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dictionary waits for an object as the key (`id`) rather than a plain integer (`NSUInteger`).

Try wrapping the integer in a `NSNumber` object.

```
CGFloat *minutes = [self.displayData objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index]];
```

Answer (score 2):

The -objectForKey: method returns a value of type `id`, but you're trying to assign that to a CGFloat*, which isn't compatible with `id` because CGFloat isn't a class. If you know that the object you're retrieving from the dictionary is a certain type, say an NSNumber, you can take steps to convert it to a CGFloat when you get it.

*Also*, you're trying to use an int as a key into a dictionary, but dictionaries require their keys to be objects too. If you want to access your objects by index, store them in an array instead of a dictionary.

Putting it all together, you'd have something like this:

```
// after changing the displayData to an array
NSNumber *number = [self.displayData objectAtIndex:index];
CGFloat minutes = [number floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a pointer like this:

```
CGFloat minutes = [self.displayData objectForKey:index];
```

Answer (score -3):

Easy question. Just don't use NSUIntegrer. Instead of it, do the following:

```
id index;//then set the index
```